# Facebook JavaScript API for google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I make a chrome extension to like specific page posts automatically.
With a simple popup controller and background thread to handle fb api interactive

I cannot load facebook js api into extension page with official example method.

The script **[jssdk](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js)** was loaded and executed checked by chrome developer tools.

But window.FB is not defined by script loaded!!!

- I also add script tag manually.
- It appeared both background thread and popup window.
- If inject with iframe to load page, it will success loaded window.FB and popup a login/authenticate window. But it had a cross domain problem!
- The div#fb-root is exist.
- **menifest.json** has **content_security_policy**

  - script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but this might lead you in the right direction.

The problem might be with the document.location of the extension document. For javascript running in the extension scope, the protocol is "chrome-extension://", while many JS libraries expect either "http" or "https".

From looking at the following line at the jssdk file, it seems that FB make this assumption as well:

`var k = typeof j == 'undefined' ? location.protocol.replace(':', '') : j ? 'https' : 'http';`

Try debugging these cases, replacing the line above with something like:

`var k = 'http';`

Hope this helps.